# Error: failed to create containerd container: cannot load seccomp profile, no such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, seccomp

Trying to set a custom seccomp profile when using `kubectl apply` and despite the file being there in the container, the pod will not start with the following error:

```
Error: failed to create containerd container: cannot load seccomp profile "/var/lib/kubelet/seccomp/custom_profile.json": open /var/lib/kubelet/seccomp/custom_profile.json: no such file or directory
```

**K8 deployment YAML**

```
...
containers:
  - name: container-name
    image: container-image:version
    securityContext:
      seccompProfile:
        type: Localhost
        localhostProfile: custom_profile.json
...
```

The file is copied when the container is created and going into the shell of the pod I can see that it does exist there (when not trying to load it and the pod starts)

**Dockerfile**

```
...
COPY custom_profile.json /var/lib/kubelet/seccomp/custom_profile.json
...
```

I have also tried changing the owner (`chown`) and running with root privileges but as long as the `localhostProfile: custom_profile.json` line is in the YAML then the same error appears again.

What am I missing that is preventing the file from being found? Something missing in the YAML, something missing in the container/dockerfile?

The following article is what got me this far but still not able to set the profile: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/security/seccomp-profiles.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `type: Localhost` seccomp profile is used, then the `seccomp` profiles must be present over the node on which the pod is getting scheduled. Also, the path is relative to the path `/var/lib/kubelet/seccomp`. Here `/var/lib/kubelet/` is the default path for `kubelet` config.

Here is the related snippet from official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#seccomp):

> `localhost/<path>` - Specify a profile as a file on the node located at
> <seccomp_root>/, where <seccomp_root> is defined via the
> `--seccomp-profile-root` flag on the Kubelet. If the `--seccomp-profile-root` flag is not defined, the default path will be used, which is /seccomp where  is specified by the
> --root-dir flag.

**Example-1**: For the following to work , a `custom_profile.json` file must be present at  `/var/lib/kubelet/seccomp` path on the node.

```
securityContext:
  seccompProfile:
    type: Localhost
    localhostProfile: custom_profile.json
```

**Example-2**: For the following to work , a `custom_profile.json` file must be present at  `/var/lib/kubelet/seccomp/profiles` path on the node.

```
securityContext:
  seccompProfile:
    type: Localhost
    localhostProfile: profiles/custom_profile.json
```

**Here is a minimal working example:**

`seccomp` profiles are copied on the worker node.

```
ps@worker-node:~$ sudo ls -lrt /var/lib/kubelet/seccomp/profiles
[sudo] password for ps:
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   39 Sep 10 13:54 audit.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   41 Sep 10 13:54 violation.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1657 Sep 10 13:54 fine-grained.json
ps@worker-node:~$
```

Create the pod with the following path, notice the path is relative to `/var/lib/kubelet/seccomp`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: audit-pod
  labels:
    app: audit-pod
spec:
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: Localhost
      localhostProfile: profiles/audit.json
  containers:
  - name: test-container
    image: nginx
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

Comment: @P, thanks for the answer, that explains which file system it's looking at which is a start. "profiles are copied on the worker node" doesn't make sense, if we have several nodes (AKS agent pools) then how does this file get onto each one so that when the apply occurs it's available in /var/lib/kubelet/seccomp?

Comment: Asked another question about how to achieve the node/VMSS copy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69386845/how-to-copy-a-file-from-local-disk-to-aks-vmss-all-azure-virtual-machine-scale

Comment: Unfortunately. Its the way seccomp work . It works on the node and facilitate the pods running over it.  To overcome this, you may use a shared nfs mount between all the nodes and create a softlink.